# Specifying grails floating point precision in domain object constraint, how?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, grails

I how do I say a field is of the following type and precision in grails constraint?

```
FLOAT(7,4)
```

In mysql it means it will have value of something like `xxx.yyyy`, *3 decimal places to the left of dot and four decimal places to the right of the dot.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `max` and `scale` constraints of your domain class property to influence the schema generation. The Grails [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.3/guide/single.html#gormConstraints) explains this in detail.

From the documentation:

> ```
> someFloatValue max: 1000000, scale: 3
> ```
>
> would yield:
>
> ```
> someFloatValue DECIMAL(19, 3) // precision is default
> ```

**Note** The above is directly from the Grails documentation but logically it should yield `DECIMAL(9, 3)`.

Comment: Do you mean DECIMAL(9, 3)? how will max: 1000000, scale: 3 yield DECIMAL(19, 3)?

Comment: Agreed, it should be (9,3) but a bug in the documentation states (19,3)

Comment: DECIMAL(19, 3) is correct:
"Keep in mind that specifying only one of min/max constraints will not affect schema generation (since there could be large negative value of property with max:100, for example), unless the specified constraint value requires more digits than default Hibernate column precision is (19 at the moment)"